# How to recursively list subdirectories and their sizes?

Tags: directory, recursive, size

I have a directory with many subdirs and many files inside those. All I need is to figure out how much space each subdir takes. So I need something like `ls -lR` in that I want to see the entire directory structure all the way to each leaf, but I don't need to see individual files. Instead, I want to see how much space each subdir takes. So for example, if I have a directory `root` that has (i) subdir `foo` of size 1MB, (ii) subdir `bar` of 2MB ad a bunch of files taking up another 1MB in total, I want to see 4MB for `root`, 1MB for `foo` and 2MB for `bar`.

Comment: Look into `man du`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/57603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `du` does. Consider this example directory structure which matches what you describe in your question:

```
$ tree -h root
root
├── [4.0K]  bar
│   └── [2.0M]  file
├── [256K]  file1
├── [256K]  file2
├── [256K]  file3
├── [256K]  file4
└── [4.0K]  foo
    └── [1.0M]  file

2 directories, 6 files
```

If I now run `du` on it, I will get the output you want:

```
$ du -h root
2.1M    root/bar
1.1M    root/foo
4.1M    root
```